# What sensor to use in measuring the alcohol content for wine aging

Tags: measurement-devices

I'm a student,badly need some information about a good sensor to use for measuring the alcohol content of a wine during the aging phase. Your answers will be a great help in my future.Thank you.

Comment: As a person who makes their own wine, usually a Hydrometer is used to estimate alcohol content. If you know the amount of sugar (brix, Specific Gravity) that is in the  wine before fermentation, the yeast will ferment the drink 'dry' in which the specific gravity is about 1. This means it will have fermented out all the sugar by then. I would not expect the alcohol content to change significantly during aging. Do you still want an electronic sensor?

Comment: Yes i do want to know if there are an electronic sensor for measuring its alcohol content. Thank you sir for your kindness.

Comment: You could try a refractometer, but it's not digital in the sense you get a screen with X% abv. I think this question would be a better fit for our [Home brewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) stack-exchange. Honestly going with a good 'ole hydrometer should be good enough. It's used in chemistry labs after all.